# Unable to share/mount Volume with Docker Toolbox on Windows 10

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to setup my project with docker. I am using Docker Toolbox on Windows 10 Home. I am very new to docker. To my understanding I have to copy my files to new container and add a volume so that I can persist changes made by gulp.

Here is my folder structure

```
-- src
|- dist
|- node-modules
|- gulpfile.js
|- package.json
|- Dockerfile
```

The Dockerfile code

```
FROM node:8.9.4-alpine
RUN npm install -g gulp
CMD [ "ls", 'source' ]
```

I tried many solutions for ***docker run -v ***

e.g

```
docker run -v /$(pwd):/source <container image>
docker run -v //c/Users/PcUser/Desktop/proj:/source <container image>
docker run -v //c/Users/PcUser/Desktop/proj:/source <container image>
docker run -v //d/proj:/source <container image>
docker run -v /d/proj:/source <container image>
```

*** But No luck ***

Can anyone describe how would you set it up for yourself with the same structure. And why am I not able to mount my host folder.

P.S: If I use two containers one for compiling my code with gulp and one with nginx to serve the content of ***dist*** folder. How will I do that.

Comment: Is the user context that docker is running under a local admin on the computer?

Comment: Yes! The account belongs to admin group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@sxm1972 Thank you for your effort and help.

You are probably using Windows Pro or a server edition. I am using ***Windows 10 Home edition***

Here is how I solved it, so other people using same setup can solve their issue.

> There may be a better way to solve this, please comment if there is an efficient way.

So...

First, the question... Why I don't see my shared volume from PC in my container.

Ans: If we use docker's Boot2Docker with VirtualBox (which I am) then whenever a volume is mounted it refers to a folder *inside the Boot2Docker VM*

[Image: Result of -v with docker in VirtualBox Boot2Docker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpCKM.jpg)

So with this if we try to use `$ ls` it will show an empty folder which in my case it did.

So we have to actually mount the folder to *Boot2Docker VM* if we want to share our files from Windows environment to Container.

[Image: Resulting Mounts Window <-> Boot2Docker <-> Container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Px4MT.jpg)

To achieve this we have to manually mount the folder to VM with the following [command](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-sharedfolder)

```
vboxmanage sharedfolder add default --name "<folder_name_on_vm>" --hostpath "<path_to_folder_on_windows>" --automount
```

***IF YOU GET ERROR RUNNING THE COMMAND, SAYING vboxmanager NOT FOUND ADD VIRTUAL BOX FOLDER PATH TO YOUR SYSTEM PATH. FOR ME IT WAS `C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox`***

After running the command, you'll see `<folder_name_on_vm>` on `root`. You can check it by `docker-machine ssh default` and then `ls /`. After confirming that the folder `<folder_name_on_vm>` exist, you can use it as volume to your container.

`docker run -it -v /<folder_name_on_vm>:/source <container> sh`

Hope this helps...!

P.S If you are feeling lazy and don't wan't to mount a folder, you can place your project inside your `C:/Users` folder as it is mounted by default on the VM as show in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRlnd.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because the base-image you use runs the `node` REPL as its ENTRYPOINT. If you run the image as `docker run -it node:8.9.4-alpine` you will see a node prompt and it will not run the npm command like you want.

The way I worked around the problem is to create your own base image using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8.9.4-alpine
CMD ["sh"]
```

Build it as follows:
`docker built -t mynodealpine .`

Then build your image using this modified Dockerfile:

```
FROM mynodealpine
RUN npm install -g gulp
CMD [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "ls  source" ]
```

For the problem regarding mounting of volumes, since you are using Docker for Windows, you need to go into `Settings` (click on the icon in the system tray) and then go and enable `Shared Drives`.

Here is the output I was able to get:

```
PS C:\users\smallya\testnode> dir


    Directory: C:\users\smallya\testnode


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----        2/18/2018  11:11 AM                dist
d-----        2/18/2018  11:11 AM                node_modules
-a----        2/18/2018  11:13 AM             77 Dockerfile
-a----        2/18/2018  11:12 AM             26 gulpfile.js
-a----        2/18/2018  11:12 AM             50 package.json


PS C:\users\smallya\testnode> docker run -it -v c:/users/smallya/testnode:/source mynodealpinenew
Dockerfile    dist          gulpfile.js   node_modules  package.json
PS C:\users\smallya\testnode>
```

Comment: Node's npm command isn't my concern at this point. That is secondary objective, primary is to mount my source folder in container and persist changes.

I even tried your work around and still mount fails, well actually the command does not give any error but I don't see any files inside my container folder which is created as result of the flag `-v $(pwd):/source`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the question, possible more simple configuration via a VirtualBox graphical dialogue, worked for me, without the use of command line, albeit maybe not necessarily more versatile:

[image]

configuring the sharing folder inside VirtualBox shared folders configuration dialogue,
and then calling mount like this

```
docker run --volume //d/docker/nginx:/etc/nginx
```

> I will be binding the /etc/nginx directory in my container to
>   D:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\nginx

source:
https://medium.com/@Charles_Stover/fixing-volumes-in-docker-toolbox-4ad5ace0e572#fromHistory#fromHistory