# How to access host OS files from docker container via virtualbox on Windows 10 home

Tags: docker, windows-10, docker-volume, docker-toolbox, mount-point

I installed the Docker Toolbox on my Windows 10 home machine. When I hit the quickstart icon, I get a bash shell, and I can run a command like

```
> docker run -it ruby /bin/bash
```

That puts me into the bash shell of the docker Ruby container. That container is running on a VirtualBox VM created by the Docker Toolbox. The VM had a shared folder setting with:

```
Folder Path:  \\?\C:\Users
Folder Name:  c/Users

read-only:  unchecked
auto mount:  checked
make permanent: checked
```

I would like to be able to access the C:\Users\   folder on my Windows 10 host from my docker container via a directory called /code within the container (which is running Debian Jessie).

How can I configure my VM, or my Docker container to be able to access that folder from my docker container?

Comment: see this question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48828406/unable-to-share-volume-with-docker-toolbox-on-windows-10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key was figuring out how to express the shared volume which traversed the Windows-VirtualBox boundary, and the VirtualBox-Docker boundary.

Since the shared folder between the VirtualBox VM and Windows 10 home is C:\Users, the mount must be somewhere under that folder tree.

1. I created a folder in windows called C:\Users\Jay\MyApp. This will be visible inside the VirtualBox VM.
2. I then decided to call the folder c/MyApp in the Docker container.

The other key point is that the volume mount must start with "//". So the full docker command is:

```
docker run -it -v //c/Users/Jay/MyApp:/c/MyApp ruby /bin/bash
```

I can edit the file called C:\Users\Jay\MyApp\test.rb in Windows, using a nice text editor, and then run it in my Ruby Linux container as

```
root@ad1e3223e3c7:/# cd c/MyApp
root@ad1e3223e3c7:/c/MyApp# ruby test.rb
```

The output of test.rb appears on the console of the Docker container.